# rise the volume to maximum on Windows-Mobile 6.5

Tags: c#, windows-mobile-6.5

how to rise the volume to maximum on Windows-Mobile 6.5 using C# code

thanks

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PInvoke is what you need:

```
[DllImport("coredll.dll", , EntryPoint="waveOutSetVolume", SetLastError = true)]    
internal static extern int SetVolume(IntPtr device, int volume);

[DllImport("coredll.dll", EntryPoint="waveOutGetVolume", SetLastError = true)]    
internal static extern int GetVolume(IntPtr device, ref int volume);
```

The different level of volume:

```
public enum Volumes : int
{
    OFF = 0,
    LOW = 858993459,
    NORMAL = 1717986918,
    MEDIUM = -1717986919,
    HIGH = -858993460,
    VERY_HIGH = -1
}
```

Use this code to set the volume

```
SetVolume(IntPtr.Zero, ref volume);
```

I don't have a pocket pc development environment to check the code... Tell me if it doesn't work ;)

Comment: thanks for the help, it dosent work i got error on SetVolume(IntPtr.Zero, ref volume);

Comment: I've edited the code: I forgot to mention the name of the *pinvoked* method ;)